# Clear text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML element:

```
<div id="setProfessionalDitailsArea">
<input type="textbox" id="instituteName" placeholder="Instetute Name">
</div>
```

at some point I try to clear text box:

```
  $("#setProfessionalDitailsArea input[textbox]" ).val('');
```

But it dosen't work,while this:

```
  $("#sinstituteName" ).val('');
```

Works perfect!

Any idea why is the first option not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$("#setProfessionalDitailsArea input[type='textbox']" ).val('');
```

for more information about selectors .. this is very useful 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048